# How to score based on frequency in elasticsearch

Tags: elasticsearch

I'm using elasticsearch with a database of users. Each user has multiple jobs and each job has a career id.
I'm using the following query to find users with particular jobs:

```
"explain": true, 
"query": {
    "bool": {
        "should": [
            {
                "bool": {
                    "must": [
                        {
                            "term": {
                                  "positions.career.id": {
                                  "value": 31
                                }
                            }
                        }
                    ]
                }
            }
        ],
        "minimum_number_should_match": 1
    }
}
```

However this query gives all the results a score of 1 indicating they have that career in at least one of their positions.

I need the score to reflect the number of positions that user has.

Is there any way to do this with elasticsearch?

Answer (score 0):

You can use advanced scoring modules of elasticsearch to access index level scoring attributes to score the documents based on term frequency.

[Official documentation](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/modules-advanced-scripting.html).

You can use it inside the [function score](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/query-dsl-function-score-query.html) script score query to score based on frequency in elasticsearch

For ES 2.4.1 and default scripting language groovy

```
POST index_name1/test_type
{
  "title" : "harley harley harley",
  "nested_one" : [{
    "some_id" : 78
  },
  {
    "some_id" : 80
  },{
    "some_id" : 100
  }],
  "nested_two" : [{
    "some_id" : 79
  },
  {
    "some_id" : 80
  },{
    "some_id" : 101
  }]
}

POST index_name1/test_type
    {
      "title" : "harley harley",
      "nested_one" : [{
        "some_id" : 78
      },
      {
        "some_id" : 80
      },{
        "some_id" : 100
      }],
      "nested_two" : [{
        "some_id" : 79
      },
      {
        "some_id" : 80
      },{
        "some_id" : 101
      }]
    }

POST index_name1/_search
{
  "query": {"function_score": {
    "query": {"match_all": {}},
    "functions": [
      {"script_score": {

        "script": "_index['title']['harley'].tf()"
      }}
    ]
  }}
}
```

Following is the response for the above query.

```
{
  "took": 173,
  "timed_out": false,
  "_shards": {
    "total": 5,
    "successful": 5,
    "failed": 0
  },
  "hits": {
    "total": 3,
    "max_score": 3,
    "hits": [
      {
        "_index": "index_name1",
        "_type": "test_type",
        "_id": "AVn9aDOUKkYhaW9Iz5wL",
        "_score": 3,
        "_source": {
          "title": "harley harley harley",
          "nested_one": [
            {
              "some_id": 78
            },
            {
              "some_id": 80
            },
            {
              "some_id": 100
            }
          ],
          "nested_two": [
            {
              "some_id": 79
            },
            {
              "some_id": 80
            },
            {
              "some_id": 101
            }
          ]
        }
      },
      {
        "_index": "index_name1",
        "_type": "test_type",
        "_id": "AVn9aBQGKkYhaW9Iz5wJ",
        "_score": 2,
        "_source": {
          "title": "harley harley",
          "nested_one": [
            {
              "some_id": 78
            },
            {
              "some_id": 80
            },
            {
              "some_id": 100
            }
          ],
          "nested_two": [
            {
              "some_id": 79
            },
            {
              "some_id": 80
            },
            {
              "some_id": 101
            }
          ]
        }
      },
      {
        "_index": "index_name1",
        "_type": "test_type",
        "_id": "AVn9aBhlKkYhaW9Iz5wK",
        "_score": 2,
        "_source": {
          "title": "harley harley",
          "nested_one": [
            {
              "some_id": 78
            },
            {
              "some_id": 80
            },
            {
              "some_id": 100
            }
          ],
          "nested_two": [
            {
              "some_id": 79
            },
            {
              "some_id": 80
            },
            {
              "some_id": 101
            }
          ]
        }
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

Hope this helps.